# UnicodeEncodeError when fetching url

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, urlfetch, python-unicode

I have this issue trying to get all the text nodes in an HTML document using lxml but I get an UnicodeEncodeError: `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 8995: ordinal not in range(128)`. However, when I try to find out the type of encoding of this page (`encoding = chardet.detect(response)['encoding']`), it says it's `utf-8`. It seems weird that a single page has utf-8 and ascii. Actually, this:

```
fromstring(response).text_content().encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

solves the problem.

Here it's my code:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import urllib2
import chardet
request = urllib2.Request(my_url)
request.add_header('User-Agent',
                   'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)')   
request.add_header("Accept-Language", "en-us")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()

print encoding
print fromstring(response).text_content()
```

Output:

```
utf-8
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 8995: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What can I do to solve this issue?. Keep in mind that I want to do this with a few other pages, so I don't want to encode on an individual basis.

**UPDATE:**

Maybe there is something else going on here. When I run this script on the terminal, I get a correct output but when a run it inside SublimeText, I get UnicodeEncodeError... ¿?

**UPDATE2:**

It's also happening when I create a file with this output. `.encode('ascii', 'replace')` is working but I'd like to have a more general solution.

Regards

Comment: Does `print u"\u00A9"` inside your script also produce the error?

Comment: Yes. UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) :-)

Comment: you could set PYTHONIOENCODING to whatever character encoding SublimeText accepts.

Comment: Where do I do that?. Is it related to export PYTHONIOENCODING='utf-8'?

Comment: yes. It is an environment variable, see http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails Note: the output encoding has nothing to do with the original encoding of html page

Comment: See here: http://bit.ly/unipain

Comment: I updated SublimeText just today and I'm not getting this issue. Have you tried this with the latest update (2.0 final)? What platform are you running on?

Comment: I just updated but I haven't tested this. I will do that. Thanks for the notice!

Comment: @ms4py I have tested it on Sublime Text 2.0 (final) but unfortunately I still receive "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)".

Comment: Tested both in Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try wrapping your string with repr()?
[This article](http://boodebr.org/main/python/all-about-python-and-unicode#WHYNOPRINT) might help.

```
print repr(fromstring(response).text_content())
```

Comment: This works fine in Sublime Text and also in terminal. I guess this is a workarond. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as writing out to a file as said in your edit, I would recommend opening the file with the codecs module:

```
import codecs
output_file = codecs.open('filename.txt','w','utf8')
```

I don't know SublimeText, but it seems to be trying to read your output as ASCII, hence the encoding error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your first update I would say that the terminal told Python to output utf-8 and SublimeText made clear it expects ascii. So I think the solution will be in finding the right settings in SublimeText.

However, if you cannot change what SublimeText expects it is better to use the `encode` function like you already did in a separate function.

```
def smartprint( text ) :
    if sys.stdout.encoding == None :
        print text
    else :
        print text.encode( sys.stdout.encoding , 'replace' )
```

You can use this function instead of `print`. Keep in mind that your program's output when run in SublimeText differs from Terminal. Because of the `replace` accented characters will loose their accents when this code is run in SublimeText, e.g. `é` will be shown as `e`.